# How to create UI in Python 3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, user-interface

I need to know if it's possible to create a UI for my Python application. I created a very simple programm that you can see ***[here](https://github.com/feRpicoral/Biologia)*** and i would like to create a UI, so the user can use it like a "real program", not only in CMD/Python Shell.

And another thing: to the user be able to use the program without downloading the code and Python, I'm using ***[this site](http://pytoexe.com/)*** to transform my `.py` files in `.exe` files. But, when I try to download it, Google Chrome and Windows Defender says that the '.exe' it's a malware (you can try downloading the '.exe' files at my GitHub ***[here](https://github.com/feRpicoral/Biologia/tree/master/exe)***). How can i solve that? (I know that disabling the anti-virus will fix it but the user probably won't do that.)
Thank you for the help guys!

Comment: try PyQt5, it is a wrapper to c++ qt5

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter or GTK are both very good. I also recommend using Glade https://glade.gnome.org/ as a GUI designer with GTK

Comment: Can you help me to install it? I really suck using GIT Bash

Comment: If its GTK you are referring you, and your using a Microsoft Windows OS, then you may find the GTK all in one installer useful: http://www.pygtk.org/downloads.html I believe the installer provided by pygtk supports up to 2.7

Answer (score 0):

On the Python Bytes podcast they've dedicated a few recent episodes to discussing the state of Python GUI frameworks starting from [episode 62](https://pythonbytes.fm/episodes/show/62/wooey-and-gooey-are-simple-python-guis). I suggest you give them a listen to get an overview and determine what's most useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is an inbuilt GUI module for python. Your computer is likely to be suspicious of any file not from a verified publisher.